# Downgrade Geoserver from 2.12 to 2.10

Tags: geoserver

Can I do a downgrade just by over-installing , i.e.  deploying the war file of the older version, without losing settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general upgrades are supported configuration wise, but there is no guarantee about downgrades, it may or may not work.

Suggestion: backup the data directory and try, there is a good chance it's going to work.
Next time you upgrade, best do a backup of the data dir before running the new GeoServer, this will ensure a smooth downgrade if you need to.